# How do I install Burg in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, burg

When I try installing Burg, I get the following error:

```
Package burg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package burg-themes is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'burg' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'burg-themes' has no installation candidate
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, as a dualboot with Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. From [**this page**](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-in-ubuntu/), its say that you need to add PPA to install burg. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

Burg is not in the official repositories of Ubuntu, to install it you have to add the Burg's PPA first.

to do so, run the following commands

get into super user mode

`sudo -s`

add burgs repository

`add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg`

update your repositories and install burg

`aptitude update`

`aptitude install burg burg-themes`

Comment: and now i get message :

 `root@rnd-rose:~# aptitude install burg burg-themes
No candidate version found for burg      
No candidate version found for burg-themes
No candidate version found for burg
No candidate version found for burg-themes
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.` 

so what i must do??